# How to select mutiple values with like clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.7

```
SELECT * 
from table 
WHERE column LIKE "AAA%" 
   OR column LIKE "BBB%" 
   OR column LIKE "CCC%"
```

I have more than 10 values to select, so it is not appropriate to write like the above example. Is there any way to select possible values in one sentence? I am using MySQL.

Comment: Is the column indexed ???

Comment: You could put the values into a table?

Comment: No. i want to find a value by using keywords.

Answer (score 5):

This case is a good candidate for using `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`.

```
SELECT * 
from table 
WHERE column REGEXP '^(AAA|BBB|CCC)'
```

`REGEXP` is case insensitive. For case sensitive searches use `REGEXP BINARY`.

```
SELECT * 
from table 
WHERE column REGEXP BINARY '^(AAA|BBB|CCC)'
```

`REGEXP` can't benefit from indexes, so it may only be an efficient option if `LIKE` wouldn't use indexes either. With multiple `LIKE` statements that could individually access an index (like in your case if *column* is indexed and the like has a wildcard at the end), performing `UNION` of individual queries with a single `LIKE` would probably be most effective in a large dataset.

However, if your query filter primarily by, say, a range of dates, then a single `REGEXP` may be faster than multiple `LIKE`s `OR`ed.

For more information about `REGEXP` in MySQL see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html).

Comment: Is it possible to use REGEXP with value with space. for example,    SELECT * 
from table 
WHERE column REGEXP '^(AAA  aa|BBB bb|CCC)'

Comment: @T.Su - yes, space is ok.  It will match exactly one space, not table or carriage return, etc.  `REGEXP` _may_ be faster than a 10-way `UNION`; it depends on various things.

Comment: It only came out which starts with those words. I want to select a sentence which include those words. those keywords might be anywhere of the sentences. So how can i select?

Comment: Sure (your question implied you only wanted to check the start: `LIKE 'AAA%'`). Just remove the caret symbol, which is an anchor to the start of the line (`^`) and the test will be over the whole string. Note that it won't make use of indexes when you search like that.

Comment: SELECT * from table WHERE column REGEXP '^AAA aa|BBB bb|CCC'      is it like that?

Comment: `'AAA|BBB|CCC'`, no anchor (`^`). The pipe (`|`) is like the logical OR.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using Dynamic SQL

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ''',prfx,'%''')
SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
INTO @sql FROM (SELECT 'AAA' prfx UNION SELECT 'BBB' UNION SELECT 'CCC') pfxkeys;
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

So that you understand what this is doing, please note what `@sql` becomes:

```
mysql> SELECT @sql\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@sql: SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'AAA%' UNION SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'BBB%' UNION SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'CCC%'
```

Let me format the output a little more

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'AAA%' UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'BBB%' UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'CCC%'
```

The only thing you need to focus on in scripting the `pfxkeys` subquery.

In your example, you need

```
(
    SELECT 'AAA' prfx UNION
    SELECT 'BBB'      UNION
    SELECT 'CCC'
) pfxkeys
```

If you have more prefix keys like `DDD` and `EEE`, you just add to this subquery:

```
(
    SELECT 'AAA' prfx UNION
    SELECT 'BBB'      UNION
    SELECT 'CCC'      UNION
    SELECT 'DDD'      UNION
    SELECT 'EEE'
) pfxkeys
```

Comment: This 10-table `UNION` _may_ be faster than `REGEXP`; it depends on a lot of things.

Comment: An optimization:  Since there is no overlap in what the `SELECTs` will find (in this case), change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.  (`UNION` defaults to `UNION DISTINCT`, which needs a de-dupping pass.)

Comment: It is OK to include `prfx` in every `SELECT`; this may make the code generation a tiny bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison values can be held in a separate table and joined to the data table. This assumes the comparision clauses do not overlap, as you sample shows. In other words, each data row will match at most one filter condition.

This is the data:

```
create table data  (c1 char(10));

insert data(c1) values ('aa1'),('aa2'),('bb1'),('bb2'),('cc1'),('cc2');
```

An these are the 10+ comparison values

```
create table comparison  (c2 varchar(5));

insert comparison (c2) values ('aa%'), ('bb%');
```

So the query becomes:

```
select * 
from data as d
inner join comparison as l
    on d.c1 like l.c2;
```